# How to search multiple SQL Server databases with .NET code-first

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I wrote a b2b project. There are firms and firms' periods. There is a database for every firm.

Every firm has clients and clients have Username and password but one client can have many firms. As a client login in to the database, I have to search in every firm whether I am in that firm/database or not. It's currently too expensive.

For example:

```
Firm
X          --> Client table -->  Jason  12345 Jason@...
Y          --> Client table -->  Mark   2233  Mark@...,.mary 888 mary@.. 
Z          --> Client table -->  Jenifer  111  J@...,jack .. , Mark,...,...,....,...
When user(Mark) login, he has to loop in all db if he exists(x,y,z,t...).
```

I am trying to list if Mark (Mark's email is recorded) has more than 1 company. I am looping with foreach context.

I don't know there is another way to do it. Is there?

Database table names (client user table) are the same.

I have an idea: in the master database, if I create a client user record. May I do login operations here or not?

Is there anyone who can help me out?

I'm using

- SQL Server
- .NET Core, Entity Framework code-first

Comment: Is that Entity Framework **Core**, too ? Or are you using the "old" EF v6 on .NET Core?

Comment: Entity Framework Core

Answer (score 1):

You should have a separate "master" database that stores the (Firm,Client) pairs and the connection strings to every Firm database.  When a client logs in search  the master database for the Firms the client has access to.

Comment: you are right David

Comment: in sql structure ,A new database is created for each firm and firm's period in sql so
Why was there no clients table in the master database. Because I want to use relationship.the best solition. Selecting the firm and period when the client wants